# Kubernetes Git Volume how to add private key?

Tags: git, bitbucket, kubernetes

Read the documents but can not work out how to add a key for a git bitbucket repository.

Don't want to have to create another container to just to checkout from git to populate a EmptyDir to share common data between pods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in the [git volume mounting code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/volume/git_repo/git_repo.go) that handles private keys. It's likely that it currently only supports publicly accessible git repositories. Feel free to file a feature request to add support for private repositories.